# Jquery: What HTML element initiated ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I several HTML elements that initiate ajax when clicked. How can I check which element was clicked inside the `ajaxComplete` event?

I tried `event.target` but it returns the entire document.

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
    if ( settings.url.indexOf("somelink/hello") > -1) {
         console.log("return here element that initiated ajax")
    }
});
```

Note: The tricky part - I don't have access to the ajax request that is sent on click. I can't configure the code that makes the request. I can only check when the ajax is complete.

I first need to run the `ajaxComplete` event then check which element initiated ajax because I need to add some html to that element. For this reason I'm trying to check in the `ajaxComplete` event.

Comment: Where are the HTML  elements that initiate this thing? Currently it is bound to the document

Comment: in the document. on the same page

Comment: I understand, but show me how that initiates it!

Comment: On click, an ajax request is sent. I don't have access to the ajax request. I can only check when it is complete.

Comment: based on: *"i don't have access to the code that makes the ajax request"* i'd have to go with what you are trying to do can't be done, unless you can hook into the click event. but even then, you can't be 100% sure you catch the correct ajax request unless you can access the ajax request directly.

Comment: Put another way, you're trying to solve this problem from the wrong end.You need to get to the ajax request somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best and easiest way is to store the element in a global variable when you send the ajax call. Set it to the event.target.activeElement. Then in your ajaxComplete you can just access that var to change CSS etc.

Upon further consideration, if you use my solution you would have to limit it to one ajax request at a time. Otherwise a new ajax request would overwrite variable if the initial ajax request hadn't completed yet. I'd take Palpatime's answer.

Comment: that returns the entire document

Comment: So you are attaching the the initial ajax request to one of the document's events (if so, which one?), or are you attaching it to individual HTML element events? If the latter, are you using the on() to apply it to certain types of elements within the document?

Comment: attaching to individual html elements on click

Comment: In that case, I will revise answer.

Comment: A simple variable will fail if there are simultaneous calls. You'll need to store the associate the caller to the request somehow. I'm not clear how you will find a unique key to store it with, though, since the `jqXHR` object doesn't seem to expose any method to retrieve the internal jQuery XHR ID.

Comment: I agree Palpatime. Your solution is best.

Comment: @david Your method might work since I can't store the element in the request. I don't have access  to the ajax request as mentioned. Could you please add an example of your code?

Comment: If you are going to use mine, be sure to check that the variable is null before initiating a new ajax request, and then in your AjaxComplete make sure to set it to null after you are done using it.  Perhaps when you initiate the ajax call you could check the var. If its not null you could do a window.SetInterval to try again in a couple of seconds.

Answer (score 2):

The `$.ajaxComplete()` handler is not an object-specific handler; you attach it to the document to be notified whenever any AJAX request completes. From the jQuery docs:

> If you must differentiate between the requests, use the parameters passed to the handler. Each time an ajaxComplete handler is executed, it is passed the event object, the XMLHttpRequest object, and the settings object that was used in the creation of the request.

So, since `settings` is a plain Object, you can extend it with a property that will then be passed to the handler, as you can see below with `requestingObjectId`. **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Palpatim/hofhbwb4/)**

```
var onComplete = function(event, jqXHR, ajaxOptions) {
    alert("Requested with " + ajaxOptions.requestingObjectId);
};

var makeRequest = function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/path/to/server',
        data: { foo: 1 },
        requestingObjectId: id
    });
};

$('button').click(makeRequest);

$(document).ajaxComplete(onComplete);
```

Comment: Actually I like your answer better than mine.  With mine you might run into issues if you initiate a new ajax call while another ajax call was waiting to complete. Cyberjunky - I'd accept Palatim's answer.

Comment: Thank you, your code works but in my situation, i cant configure the ajax request. I can't add `requestingObjectId` because i don't have access to the code that makes the ajax request. That is the problem that makes this tricky. I can only check when ajax was initiated and can see which element initiated on click event but need to somehow pair the two.

Answer (score 0):

An jQuery AjaxRequests is NOT send by an control itself. It is send by the code that the developer wrotes as event function onto this Dom element. 
Means the best thing you can get is the callee of $.ajax() by overwriting and wrapping it. And only if the callee is not written in strict mode.

I would prefer to read the documentation of that framework who is building your controls or if it is built by another company/guy contact them.

As the element is not the direct caller of the $.ajax, I see no other way.